# Unable to open an `itms-service` URL using `url_launcher` with a AWS link

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, dart, openurl, url-launcher

Hope someone has gone thru the same issue and can help me here:
I’m trying open a URL with the scheme **itms-service** using a **AWS link**  with *manifest.plist* link using [`url_launcher`](https://pub.dev/documentation/url_launcher/latest/) library but I’m getting an error:

This is only on iOS app and the point of it is to be able to force update the app if it is on a lower version, this is currently only under an Enterprise certificate and not in the AppStore

### Steps to Reproduce

```dart
 final uri = Uri(path: 'itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://awsservice.com/build/manifest.plist');
    if (await canLaunchUrl(uri)) {
      await launchUrl(uri);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
```

**Actual results (Errors):**

`\-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://awsservice.com/build/manifest.plist" - error: "Invalid input URL"`

`Failed to open URL itms-services%3A//%3Faction=download-manifest&url=https://awsservice.com/build/manifest.plist: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "invalid input parameters" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=invalid input parameters, \_LSLine=249, \_LSFunction=-\[\_LSDOpenClient openURL:fileHandle:options:completionHandler:\]}`

- I’ve tried encoding the url string but nothing seems to work: Uri(path: Uri.encodeFull(url));
- I've also tried adding itms-service as a UrlScheme. (but honestly this should be a default scheme for iOS)

**Expected results:**

Being able to open the link and download the app

Answer (score 2):

The answer was actually in the parsing of the stringL

Using `Uri.parse` is what solves it:

```
  final uri = Uri.parse(url);
    if (!await launchUrl(uri)) {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
```